# Why cornerradius takes more time to round the corner sometimes

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uibezierpath, rounded-corners

I am trying the corner of view by calling `obj.Layer.CornerRadius=3`
But sometimes it takes more time to take effect on the UI...
Whereas `UIBezierPath` and setting the mask of layer not working consistently... sometimes two corners are rounded and other two corners not rounded.

is there any consistent and effective solution for round the corners in xamarin.ios

FYI:
I am rounding the corners at viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

```
Method 1. 
if you are making corner radius in cell then write your code inside cell.m class 
like this 
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    _btnEdit.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    _btnEdit.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
}

Method 2.
write your code on mainthread in viewdidload

Hope it works for you!!! :)
```